# How much noise does Getty Images tolerate for a contributor application?

Tags: noise, composition, stock-photography

I captured some decently pleasing pictures (when zoomed out) using Canon M50 + kit lens during the time of sunset. The image, when *not* zoomed in 100% looks well, but when zoomed in 100%, it looks considerably noisy.

How much noise does [Getty Images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_Images) tolerate for a contributor application?

Below is a sample (not the best take, but in the same lighting and exposure). Is this picture considered acceptable to be in stock, such as Getty Images?

[image]

Cropped/zoomed 100% in:

[image: Enter image description]

Comment: For anyone confused about where the noise is, you have to click on the '100% zoom' image before you can actually see it.

Answer (score 6):

IMO, this would be a poor choice for a contributor application.

It is too noisy... they want very high image quality. There may be an exception for a particular image; but not this one, and not for an application.

It is too busy/congested...what is the subject/theme? Why would a client want to buy it?

It doesn't have any commercial application... it would require a lot of model releases that you don't have. They tend to want/require model releases even if they are not actually legally required.

It wouldn't surprise me if they rejected it for trademark issues due to the recognizable signage. It can seem pretty silly.

It doesn't have any, or limited, editorial (news) application.

Comment: Of course it could be many possible cultural themes right? This is an after working hours in a train station Indonesia, a lot of social topics can be pertinent with the picture.

Comment: Unless it is a current news piece Getty would have no market for such an image... they are not interested in "social topics." The editorial market is entirely current news (sports/entertainment/war). Such an image could be submitted/accepted in relation to a story; after you have been accepted as a contributor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Getty, but it's too noisy for me.

Photoshop can fix a fair bit of that though, just with the noise reduction in CameraRAW

Before…

[image]

After…

[image]
<sub>I've over-cooked this just to make it more obvious</sub>

You have to juggle the sharpness slider with the denoise to achieve a compromise both you & Getty might be happy with.

I've avoided faces in this example, but they work quite well too. I have no real idea how strict Getty are on needing releases for anyone recognisable in a photo, so I just avoided the issue.